# mmap allocation returns 0xfffffffffffffff4 (not MAP_FAILED)

Tags: c, linux, mmap, errno

I am trying to allocate memory using mmap, here is the code:

```
long long *copy;
copy = (long long*)mmap(NULL,
                       (size_t)1024,
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

  if (copy == MAP_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed (Process aborted)\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Pointer: %p\n", copy);
```

Obviously, I check if the allocation fails. When this happens I should get -1 from what I gather from the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#RETURN_VALUE). The thing is I get -12, well `0xfffffffffffffff4`, so the error isn't caught and the program goes on. I thought maybe its because of the `(long long*)` cast, but a cast shouldn't change the pointer value. So I am very curious as to why this happens and how to prevent it.

**More strange behavior:**

I tried to print the `errno`. If I use `printf("%d\n", errno);` it prints 0 and the pointer is still set to `0xfffffffffffffff4`. But if I use `err(errno, "%p", copy);` then it prints:

```
program.exe: 0x7f8130981000: Success
```

And now the pointer is valid, but I can't use it because `err` terminated the execution.

Comment: `program.exe` — are you on Windows?  Are you using MinGW or Cygwin or something else?

Comment: No I can see how that can be misleading, I am on linux but I specify the .exe extension for organisation purposes

Comment: Your problem may well be the cast of the return of `mmap`. In C, this is never necessary and can hide bugs. Maybe you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` ? Maybe you haven't switched alll warnings on ? `-Wall` could tell you more.

Comment: There's no excuse for this suggestion to work, but have you tried `printf("Pointer: %p\n", (void *)copy)`?  (OK: there's half an excuse if it works, but it seems improbable that it will make any difference.)

Comment: You'd probably get better help by providing a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Jens Gustedt the -Wall switch is on no warnings

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried all the different casts without success

Comment: No surprise that the cast didn't change anything.  I once worked on a machine where it would have mattered, but that was in the early 80s, and the machines are no longer available.  (I still remember the tremendous boost we got by increasing the memory from 1MB to 2MB!)

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror -Wextra` as well as `-Wall`?  Again, if you've included the necessary headers, this won't change things — if you're a careful coder.  If you've not included the necessary headers, or you're a careless coder, you may have more work to do than you expected.  (I use those options all the time; I don't get a chance to be a careless coder — at least, not in the sense of running into problems because of bugs those options identify.)  Also, what happens if you use `warnc()` instead of `err()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Using the flags you suggested, I realized `<err.h>` wasn't included. When I did include it this happened:
`program.exe: 0xfffffffffffffff4: Success`
So the implicit declaration of err made it work? Also as Gene suggested I am working on an MCVE but I can't seem to be able to replicate this behavior.

Comment: I strongly counsel using the prototypes options — it prevents such issues.  Not including `<err.h>` made it fail in different, more creative ways — you don't know whether the pointer `err()` printed was valid because the program exited.  I've not seen behaviour like what you're seeing (except in your proto-MCVE) very often, especially when the correct headers are included and functions declared.  On Linux (and some, perhaps many, other systems), error 12 is ENOMEM.  Is there any danger of a funny mapping function being used that converts a `-1` error code into `-errno`?  Getting outlandish…

Comment: That would make sens because I am indeed mapping more than one region. I will try to see if correcting a possible mapping issue will solve it.

Comment: The correct header for `mmap()` is `sys/mman.h`, per both [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) and [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). Where does `err.h` come from?

Comment: To use the `err()` function to know if the call to `mmap()` succeeded. And it does according to `errno`, but the value returned is not a valid pointer. All the other includes were fine.

Comment: the global variable `errno` is not available unless you have this statement: `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: when compiling on linux, always enable all the warnings.  at a minimum use: `gcc -c -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 myprogram.c -o myprogram.o`

Answer (score 0):

When compiling with all the warnings (`-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror -Wextra`), as suggested in the comments, I realized `<err.h>` wasn't included. When I included it, the "strange behavior" that I described at the end of my question disappeared; the program behaved normally but still with a bad pointer, I didn't know it but at this point the program would have worked if I didn't check the `errno`.

In some other parts of the code, I have assembly-written functions that have always been working great (that's why I thought the mistake wasn't related to them). But then I remember that some of them use `%rbx` to pass information between them, but it just so happens that `%rbx` is the register used for `errno` in gcc.

So looking at the generated assembly code for that function, I realized `%rbx` wasn't "protected" by the compiler. Adding to the headers `<errno.h>` fixed that, and now everything is working fine.

Even though it seems to work without the proper includes, this is definetly a lesson to be more careful and always use the maximum warning options.

Comment: What do you mean by "wasn't protected"? `rbx` is a callee saved register and it's your job to save and restore it if you use it in hand-written assembly. You should know this before writing assembler by hand.

Comment: The thing is it works now that all the correct header files have been included (and the assembler functions didn't change). I don't know why though. I noticed that when the correct files had been included `%rsp` was decremented a coupe of bytes more before the call to `mmap()`, maybe there was an overwriting issue.